# Image won't show up from JavaScript coding

Tags: javascript

The result of this code should show an image floating however I messed up somewhere and the error system on my text editor ( the one that puts the red Xs in the margin, I forgot what it's called ) is disabled and I can't seem to find how to turn it on.

```js
// CONSTANTS
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
var NANONAUT_WIDTH = 118;
var nanonautX = CANVAS_WIDTH - NANONAUT_WIDTH;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
var NANONAUT_HEIGHT = 229;
var GROUND_Y = 540;
// SETUP
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var nanonautImage = new Image();
nanonautImage.src = "dad.png";

var nanonautX = 50;
var nanonautY = 40;

window.addEventListener("load", start);

function start() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
// MAIN LOOP
function mainLoop() {
  update();
  draw();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
// PLAYER INPUT
// UPDATING
function update() {
  
}
// DRAWING
function draw() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
  
  c.drawImage(nanonautImage, nanonautX, nanonautY);
}
```

Comment: Make sure `dad.png` is available. Your code shows an image if i insert a different one.

Comment: Most likely means that the process that was triggered by assigning a value to `nanonautImage.src` which attempted to load `dad.png` was aborted or encountered an error.

Comment: dad.png is available.

Comment: Are any errors output in your browser's javascript console (Ctl-shift-I)?